# vimrc write to file

Tags: vim

I've been trying to use vim to simplify writing latex. To this end, I want to write a function to make it easy to write matrices. Here's what I want it to do.

While in insert mode

if I type mmatrix (not a typo. I want two m's)

I want it to ask me the number of rows and columns I need

Then open a blank matrix with the required number of placeholders (denoted <++>)

Here's the code I wrote

```
imap mmatrix <C-o>:call Matrix
func! Matrix(rows, columns)
    for row in a:rows
       for col in a:columns
           exec "normal! i<++>&  "
       endfor
       exec "normal! i\\\\ <CR>"
    endfor
endfunction
```

So for a 2x2 Matrix, it should look like

```
<++>& <++>\\
<++>& <++>\\
```

However, this isn't working. May I know how to modify this file to make it do what I want it to?

Comment: After some searching I found out how the imap ought to be edited. I still don't know how to print to file though.

Comment: I've found a way around printing too. I'm just not sure how to line break now. The <CR> doesn't seem to do any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work:

```
func! Matrix(rows, columns)
   for row in range(a:rows)
      for col in range(a:columns)
          exe "norm i<++>&  "
      endfor
      exe "norm Xi\\\\\\\<cr>"
   endfor
endfunction
```

another option would be using a command instead of an imap, like:

```
command! -nargs=1 M :call Matrix(<args>)
```

then you could use `:M 2,4` in normal mode to call the function.

Comment: Thanks! What does Xi do? I know X is to delete and i to insert, but why have you used it in that particular way?

Comment: `X` delete's the character before the cursor when you're in normal mode. Because the function prints `"<++>& "` in a loop, when the loop finishes there is an extra space left on the end of the line. The example of what you want doesn't have a space in between the `&` and the backslashes, so I use `X` to delete that space before inserting the backslashes and return character. In this instance, `x` wouldn't work because after printing the other statements the cursor is over the "new line" symbol. `X` seemed to be a simple way of eliminating that problem.